# Natural Powers of Unbounded Operators densely defined

Tags: operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be a closed densely defined operator on some Hilbert space $H$ with non-empty resolvent set
$$
\rho(A)=\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} ; (\lambda - A)^{-1} \in L(H) \}.
$$
Then the operators $A^n$ are closed and densely defined for all integers $n \geq 0$.

**Question:** I was able to show that $A^n$ is closed but why is it also densely defined?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to have a look into the book *Unbounded linear operators. Theory and applications* of Goldberg, S. 1966. Lemma 2.7 of Chapter IV gives quite weak conditions for the domain of the product of two operators to be dense. Your statement follows easily thereof.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2026635)